# Shrink menu on scroll flickers on "point of shrinking"

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop, shrink

My header/menu is flickering on scrolling down till the "point of shrinking" (in my example on 300px). I've tested different heights but every time I came to "the point" it's flickering because it's adding and deleting the class "small".

```
 /* === Shrink Header on Scroll === */

var header = $('.site-header');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ( scroll >= 300 ) {
        header.addClass('small');
    }
    else {
        header.removeClass('small');
    }
});
```

I can produce this flickering only on Chrome and with slow scrolling (Version 86.0.4240.111)

Comment: Did you check if there is any other code that adds the "small" class ? It is not possible that the shown code adds the class small and then removes it, these conditions are mutual exclusive.

Comment: @Lapskaus  I can't find any other code that adds this class. Heres the Page: http://192.168.1.106:3000  Only the logo is shrinking and the paddings ... probably because the shrinking means that the scroll distance no longer fits? ...

Comment: i won't be able to look at a page on your local machine

Comment: @Lapskaus oh ups. Sorry wrong link... https://boes.concept-design-heumann.de/

Comment: works as intended on the link you provided. Try to reload the local page with [CTRL] + [F5] to override cached scripts

Comment: @Lapskaus I also tested the current status again in different browsers. It's flickering only in Chrome. (and on slow scrolling)

Comment: Try to add a condition to your else. Sth like `else if (scroll < 280)` to create an offset between the two conditions.